# What is the proportion of Black Clover manga covered by the anime until episode 170?

Tags: black-clover

As of today, the Black Clover manga is listed as "Publishing" in MyAnimeList, while the anime has "Finished Airing" at episode 170.

As of today, how many chapters does the manga have? Episode 170 corresponds to which chapter?

*(please don't give spoilers from the manga - I just want to know how much extra story there is in the manga, proportionally)*

Answer (score 1):

Well in manga (MangaFox) which I have been reading is of  **Spade Kingdom Raid Arc**

Chapter 272

**Edit:** Since yuo asked about other Arcs I will list them out below:

1. Magic Knights Entrance Arc - 10 chaps
2. Dungeon Exploration Arc - 11 chaps
3. Royal Capital Arc - 16 chaps
4. Eye of the Midnight Sun Arc - 19 chaps
5. Seabed Temple Arc - 17 chaps
6. Witches' Forest Arc - 28 chaps
7. Royal Knights Arc - 45 chaps
8. Elf Reincarnation Arc - 81 chaps
9. Heart Kingdom Joint Struggle Arc - 32 chaps
10. Spade Kingdom Raid Arc - Still Ongoing ( I just mentioned till the latest one and not determining it as the final chapter in this Arc)

Comment: Hello, thank you. And how many chapters are there in total?

Comment: There are around 290 chapters in this arc and there might be another arc starting soon I guess

Comment: I am confused, is it 290 chapters in total or just in the latest arc?

Comment: Not in total sorry I should have said it only in the latest Arc

Comment: Thanks. In your answer, you say chapter 272, is it 272 from the latest arc or 272 in total?

Comment: @PedroA There is 290 in total in the latest arc and one of the chapter no.272 is from the latest arc and I was mentioning chapter 272 since you asked the follow up question as _" Episode 170 corresponds to which chapter?"_ that's why :)

Comment: Awesome!! And what other arcs existed before this one? How many chapters were there in them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123214/discussion-between-itoh-atsushi-and-pedro-a).